# Closest() in jQuery doesn't work when at the same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem:**

I want (after clicking on a button - this part is OK) to select the closest element with a class `.my-textarea`, but the using of `prev()` is not always possible, because the code is dynamic. Could you help?

**Details:**

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Description:</div>
    <textarea class="my-textarea" name="my-textarea" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="my-submit" name="my-submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

And my JS code (in on button with class "my-submit" click event) is:

`var text = $(this).closest('.my-textarea').val();`

But it's not working. I am getting undefined.

If I tried:-

`var text = $(this).prev().val();`

I will get the text of the text-area, but as I've mentioned, my code is dynamic and the order and number of elements will change. So, `prev()` is out of option.

Any idea how to make `closest()` work?

Comment: your missing the `.` on the first call to show its a class name `$(this).closet('.my-textarea').val();`

Comment: try $(this).parent().find('textarea[name=my-textarea]').val()

Comment: Assuming `this` is the button, try `$(this).parent().find('textarea')`.

Comment: Read the docs, `closest` traverses up the down, it ignores siblings, you can use `prev`, `next` or `siblings` to find neighboring elements

Comment: Instead of selecting the closest, why dont you refer to the textarea you want to submit? This way  you can be sure it is the right one.

Comment: @TeaTime I have multiple forms in li elements, I need use closest search method.

Comment: Try using `siblings`. You can pass a selector into it to filter what you want, e.g. `$(this).siblings('textarea')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to Use `siblings()` instead of `closest()`:-

```js
$('.my-submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();
  console.log(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Description:</div>
    <textarea class="my-textarea" name="my-textarea" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="my-submit" name="my-submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `.siblings()` might be more general.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this better than using `.parent().find('textarea')` ?

Comment: @JohnDoeherskij  use  of siblings is better in your case. `.parent().find('textarea')` will only create overhead (complexcity).

Answer (score 6):

I always select parent and than search for child with class. That way your element can be placed virtually anywhere in parent.

```
$(this).parent().find('.my-textarea').val();
```

Comment: interesting approach. Is it less time efficient / process intensive for jquery than siblings() ?

Comment: @JohnDoeherskij Have not tested, but if you change DOM in future, you don't have to change this function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer it using class

[**closest**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will traverse up the DOM tree to look for the element, while in this case `textarea` is sibling of the button.

```
 $('.my-submit').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).siblings('.my-textarea').val();
    alert(text)
    })
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ln7vpe0/)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney check the DOM
<textarea class="my-textarea" name="my-textarea" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>